# GIS sample data for testing performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, gis, wkt

I need to test performance of queries based on spatial data. I decided to use sql server and geometry datatype.

Now I need to have sample data (for example maps, cities etc). Do You know any resources that I can  use to then load it into my database ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The U.S. Census Bureau makes all of their shape files available to the public.  See here:
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/

Once you have picked whatever shape files you want, you can import them into SQL Server using the excellent Shape2SQL tool found here:
http://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will find many good pointers, including Ordnance survey, CloudMade and Natural Earth, among answers to to this question:

**[Are there any free administrative boundaries available as shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/are-there-any-free-administrative-boundaries-available-as-shapefiles)**